# No username attribute of model error, even already have objects = UserManager()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Here is my model in the `user` app

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class UserTable(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    objects = UserManager()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my `admin.py` inside the `user` app.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import UserTable

admin.site.register(UserTable, UserAdmin)
```

I also included in my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'user.apps.UserConfig',
    ....
]
```

This is the error when I run `python manage.py migrate`

```
(admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'user.UserTable'.
The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'username', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'UserAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'user.UserTable'.
```

I dont know why, I thought when I set `objects = UserManager()` fields like `username`, `first_name`, `last_name` is setted up. I also user `USERNAME_FIELD` to set email replacing the `username` primary key.

Comment: Did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py?

Comment: No, the username field comes from `AbstractUser` from `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`, not `AbstractBaseUser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to write ur own `UserManager`

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin 

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
     if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
         **extra_fields
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

 def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
     user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password,
        **extra_fields
    )
    return user
```

Just a small comment in `UserTable` model, make

`is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)` To be able to login

And in `settings.py` file add

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.UserTable'`

**Edit**

I noticed that you are calling `AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager` in a wrong way

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
```

Try it out and told me if there is any problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser` (which does not come with a `username` field):

```
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), blank=True, null=True)
    ... # No definition for usename in this class
```

and then using `UserAdmin` (which requires `username` as field) as your admin:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    # The admin needs the username field as described by ordering
    # But your custom user model doesn't have it
    ordering = ('username',)
```

There are a number of ways to fix this, but one way is to define your own model admin for your custom user:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(UserTable, MyAdmin)
```